# using dynamic to activate JS function with c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, browser

I have this `Js` functions :

```
function Add (a, b)
{  return a+b;}

function Substract (a, b)
{  return a-b;}
```

I know (heard) that I can activate those functions on c# code using the `dynamic` keyword.

Can I get a help ( or beginning of help) to the solution by simple sample ?

### edit

If I have a webBrowser ( winform)  - which can help me. ( sorry to add this now).

Comment: What do you mean by *activating*? You need a javascript interpreter if you want to execute javascript code. The C#s `dynamic` keyword is pretty useless in this aspect.

Comment: C# can't call javascript directly (assuming your C# is server side, not in silverlight and even then I don't think you can).

Comment: @oded edited. thanks. and sorry.

Comment: @oded I saw this ,  but didnt understand completely what he has done there http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shlomo/archive/2009/06/19/c-4-0-part-2-the-quot-getcalculator-program.aspx

Comment: He is using the `WebBrowser` instance to return a javascript `Calculator` object and uses `dynamic` to call it or a winforms implementation interchangeably. Actually rather cool.

Comment: yeah Thats why I wanted to use Dynamic with my question....

Comment: @oded but he uses a  reflection there...

Comment: @RoyiNamir - That's his first example, which he then modifies to be fully dynamic.

Comment: @oded I Tink I need Optikana... let me check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a javascript interpreter if you want to execute javascript code. The C#s dynamic keyword is pretty useless in this aspect. You may take a look at [Javascript .NET](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/) or [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) if you are trying to execute those functions in .NET code.

Here's an example with `Jint`:

```
using System;
using Jint;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var script = @"
function Add(a, b) {  
    return a + b;
}

function Substract(a, b) {  
    return a - b;
}

return Add(a, b);
";
        var result = new JintEngine()
            .SetParameter("a", 3)
            .SetParameter("b", 5)
            .Run(script);

        Console.WriteLine("result: {0}", result);
    }
}
```

Remark: what you have is not valid javascript. The `var` keyword cannot be used before function parameters. So you probably should start by fixing your code.

Comment: Does this libarary can help me to activate "add" in c# ?

Comment: fixed ( that is what heppens when you're in hurry :) )

Comment: @RoyiNamir, yes, the library can help you call the Add javascript function. But first you will have to fix it as what you have shown is not valid javascript as I stated in my answer.

Comment: youre the man! thanks ! ( although I wanted to use the Dynamic keyword...) but thanks a lot.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, the dynamic keyword cannot parse javascript. It's purpose is far from that.

Comment: @Darin - the document he linked to in the comments uses a `WebBrowser` object that returns a javascript `Calculator` dynamic type that gets invoked.

Comment: @Oded, yes, it uses the built-in WebBrowser javascript interpreter. The returned object could be manipulated through reflection and the .NET dynamic keyword simplifies this manipulation.